# How to work with or merge two separate arrays of keywords in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, array-merge

I have a recurring need to merge two arrays of information. This is happening very often and run possibly 20+ times per page load, so I want to ensure I am attacking this in the most speed-friendly efficient way.

The function receives a list of `text` keywords and creates a simple `unique` array of the keywords.

The challenge is then taking these keywords, and getting their associated `filenames.html` from a database (I used medoo, but that's irrelevant) and be able to present **2** different link types based on the result, which are :

A) where the `filename.html` exists  (or)
B) to a `.php` file that can handle the keyword as a query (i.e., a static file for the keyword doesn't exist so instead send the user to a `.php?=the_keyword` to present an appropriate page).

I am somewhat confident that I have made this more **elongated** that it could be - This is how I am approaching this so far:

```
 $unique_best_keywords = array_unique($best_keywords);
 $keywords_to_display = array();
 $keywords_to_find = array();
 foreach ($unique_best_keywords as $keyword) {
    unset($keyword_to_clean);
    if (in_array($keyword, $flagged_keywords, TRUE) !== TRUE) {
        $keyword_to_clean = strtolower(trim($keyword));
        $keyword_to_clean = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', '-', $keyword_to_clean);
        $keyword_to_clean = preg_replace('/-+/', "-", $keyword_to_clean);
        $keywords_to_display[] = array (
                "anchor_text" => trim($keyword),
                "file_name" => $keyword_to_clean);
    }
}
```

The example result here would be `anchor_text: "jobs at apple"` and `file_name: "jobs-at-apple"`.

The keyword with dashes in it, is the `index` in my database to query for matching static html files - so I approach this like the following:

```
    if (isset($keywords_to_display) && !empty($keywords_to_display)) {
    foreach ($keywords_to_display as $keyword_to_call_from_db) {
        $keywords_to_find[] = $keyword_to_call_from_db['file_name'];
    }
    unset($keyword_topic_view_links);
    $keyword_topic_view_links = $database->select("my_database_table", array(
        "filename_dot_html"), array("unique_filename_index" => $keywords_to_find)); // medoo db query
    }
}
if (isset($keyword_topic_view_links) && is_array($keyword_topic_view_links)) {
    $view_links = array();
    foreach ($keyword_topic_view_links as $a_link) {
        $view_links[] = $a_link['filename_dot_html'];
    }
}

                    if (isset($keyword_topic_view_links) && isset($keywords_to_display)) {
                        foreach ($keywords_to_display as $keyword) {
                        if (count($view_links) < 1) {

// Send all keywords to the .php file to present a nice page -- dynamic!
                            unset($keyword_display,$keyword_display_file);
                            $keyword_display = $keyword['anchor_text'];
                            $keyword_display_file = $keyword['file_name'];
                            $html_output .= '<a href="/presentable.php?keyword=' . $keyword_display_file . '">' . $keyword_display . ' </a>';

                        } else {

// Send some topics views to static html pages-- 

unset($keyword_display,$keyword_display_file,$keyword_display_file_html);
                        $keyword_display = $keyword['anchor_text'];
                        $keyword_display_file = $keyword['file_name']; 
                        $keyword_display_file_html = "$keyword_display_file.html";
                            if (in_array($keyword_display_file_html, $view_links) !== TRUE) { 

// Keyword WAS NOT in the db array!

                                $html_output .= '<a href="/presentable.php?keyword=' . $keyword_display_file . '">' . $keyword_display . ' </a>';

} else {     

// Keyword WAS IN in the db array! Yay!
 $html_output .= '<a href="/' . $keyword_display_file_html . '">' . $keyword_display . ' </a>';

                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    }
```

Any advice / optimisations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might just be a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). It is hard to judge, seeing you provide a lot of code. Could you try to explain the core problem and create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes, it is an XY problem. Thanks for the edits, but I'm not proficient enough to simplify. My code works, but I fear there are more un-speedy iterations/foreach loops than necessary. I have achieved similar using array_intersect instead of in_array for other functions, but I don't see that as a 'volume of iterations optimisation'.